# X is Banach iff $\sum_{n \geq 1} y_n$ converges, where $\left \| y_n \right \| \leq 2^{-n}, \forall n$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Prove that the normed space $X$ is Banach space if and only if $\sum_{n \geq 1} y_n$  converges, where $\left \| y_n \right \| \leq 2^{-n}$ for all $n$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? Can you get one of the directions?

Comment: I think of the lemma "$X$ is Banach space iff every absolutely convergent series converges". Can you give a direction?

Comment: Definitions are another good place to start.  What extra condition is required, for a normed linear space $X$ to be a Banach space?

Comment: Just read the *proof* of the lemma you mention, and observe that it gives you the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A cauchy sequence is convergent iff it has a convergent subsequence.